# Shared access policy for storing images in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to update expiry time of shared access policy of blob container through Azure portal?

Is it possible to set indefinite expiry time for shared access policy? I have an application which has html editor where users upload images to Azure blob storage. So they can upload images and see them through generated uri. I used shared access policy with READ permission so that users can see images inside html? Is it good practice to set indefinite expiry time of shared access policy with READ permission?

I don't want my images to be public, I just want authenticated users to be able to see the images. I don't understand advantage of using SAS in my case as any user having SAS can see image (for example my friend who receives image uri with sas). So, is there any advantage? Can anyone explain me this?

Comment: Where do your users authenticate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to update expiry time of shared access policy of blob
>   container through Azure portal?

As of today, it is not possible to manage shared access policies on the blob container using Azure Portal. You would need to use some other tools or write code to do so.

> Is it possible to set indefinite expiry time for shared access policy?

You can create a shared access policy without specifying an expiry time. What that means is that you would need to specify an expiry time when creating a shared access signature. What you could do (though it is not recommended - more on this below) is use something like 31st December 9999 as expiry date for shared access policy.

> Is it good practice to set indefinite expiry time of shared access
>   policy with READ permission?

What is recommended is that you set expiry time to an appropriate value based on your business needs. Generally it is recommended that you keep the expiry time in the shared access signature to a small value so that the SAS is not misused as you're responsible paying for the data in your storage account and the outbound bandwidth.

> I don't understand advantage of using SAS in my case as any user
>   having SAS can see image (for example my friend who receives image uri
>   with sas). So, is there any advantage? Can anyone explain me this?

Biggest advantage of SAS is that you can share resources in your storage account without sharing storage access keys. Furthermore you can restrict the access to these resources by specifying appropriate permissions and shared expiry. While it is true that anyone with SAS URL can access the resource (in case your user decides to share the SAS URL with someone else) and it is not a 100% fool-proof solution but there are ways to mitigate these. You could create short-lived SAS URLs and also restrict the usage of SAS URLs to certain IP addresses only (IP ACLing).

You may find this link helpful regarding some of the best practices around shared access signature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#best-practices-for-using-shared-access-signatures.

Comment: Is there easy way to restrict blobs access (uri + sas) just to IP address of my web application?

Comment: It is actually the client IP address so what you need to do is figure out IP address of your user's computer and create a SAS for that IP address and return the SAS back to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if you want to change the expiry time of an ad-hoc Shared Access Signature (SAS), you need to regenerate it (re-sign it) and redistribute this to all users of the SAS. This doesn't affect the validity of the existing SAS you're currently using.

If you want to revoke a SAS, you need to regenerate the Access Key for the Storage Account that signed the SAS in the first place (which also revokes all other SASs that it has signed). If you've used the Access Key elsewhere, you'll need to update those references as well.

A good practice is to use an Access Policy rather than ad-hoc SASs, as this provides a central point of control for the:

- Start Time
- End Time
- Access permissions (Read, Write etc)

SASs linked to an Access Policy can be revoked by changing the expiry time to the past. Whilst you can delete the Access Policy to achieve the same effect, the old SAS will become valid again if you re-create the Access Policy with the same name.

It's not possible to set an indefinite expiry time for a SAS, and neither would it be good practice to - think of SASs as like shortcuts in file system to a file that bypass file permissions. A shortcut can't be revoked per-se or modified after you've created it - anyone anywhere in the world that obtains a copy would receive the same access.

For example, anyone with access to your application (or anyone with access to the network traffic, if you are using HTTP) could keep a copy of the SAS URL, and access any of the resources in that container - or distribute the URL and allow other unauthorised users to do so.

In your case, without SASs you would have served the images from a web server that required authentication (and maybe authorisation) before responding to requests. This introduces overhead, costs and potential complexity which SASs were partly designed to solve.

As you require authentication/authorisation for the application, I suggest you setup a service that generates SASs dynamically (programatically) with a reasonable expiry time, and refers your users to these URLs.

Reference: **[Using Shared Access Signatures (SAS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/#controlling-a-sas-with-a-stored-access-policy)**

Edit: [Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/) is really useful for managing Access Policies and generating SASs against them.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a very long expiry time but this is not recommended by Microsoft and no security expert will ever recommend such thing as it defies the idea of SAS

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/

As for the second part of your question, I am not sure how do you allow them to upload the images, is it directly using SAS on the container level or they post to some code in your application and the application connect to Azure Storage and upload the files?

If you have a back end service, then you can eliminate SAS and make your service works as a proxy, only your service will read and write to Azure Storage using Storage Account Access Keys and the clients will access your service to read and write the images they need, in this case the clients will not have a direct access to Azure Storage.